# Show dashboard conditionally based on authenticated user in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I have the following use case, and I appreciate that this is probably not how power-bi is intended:

I'd like a template dashboard. For which the data supplied and viewed differs per authenticated user.
A user logs in with a token via oath. This contains information on the type of dashboard he  is allowed to view. When he is logged in, a query should be ran and display his data in the template dashboard.
When another user logs in (with another id), the same query is run (with different arguments/params, based on his id), but retrieves different data. It is then displayed against the same template dashboard.

Is this at all a feasible use-case in power-bi. And if it isn't, what tooling does offer this option? It seems like most dashboarding tools are tailored towards having a single set of enterprise users, use the platform for management information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are after Row-Level Security functionality in Power BI. A good place to start is by reading the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls

Comment: Thank you. Do you know whether this can be used as a basis for a dashboard? Say you have 600 users. You'd need 600 rows with different Row-Level security definition. Can you then use a single row, corresponding with `user()` to be shown in a dashboard?

Comment: @MyName Take a look at [USERPRINCIPALNAME](https://dax.guide/userprincipalname/) DAX function. You can use it to build the [RLS rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls#using-the-username-or-userprincipalname-dax-function). Check [this article](https://radacad.com/dynamic-row-level-security-with-profiles-and-users-in-power-bi).